# LogOut в виджете входа в Telegram

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, telegram, cookie

Коллеги,

как выполнить выход пользователя из виджета входа в Telegram с сайта (через кнопку выход)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

через telegram в приложении выход выполнить можно, а с сайта нет.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал удалить cookie, но из-за другого домена не получается
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал найти функцию в telegram https://telegram.org/js/telegram-widget.js?22, там тоже нет.
Пробовал удалить из кода в js на клиенте, вообще глухо.
В сети и на сайте telegram инфы нет.

Кто решал эту задачу, дайте совет.
Пишу на vue js, node js